# How to remove "search" in Request::url()?

Tags: laravel-backpack

I am setting-up a nested resource to manange User's Posts based on this tutorial: https://backpackforlaravel.com/articles/tutorials/nested-resources-in-backpack-crud.

Problem is that the URL generated by the Request::url() in the button adds "search" like so:

```
<a href="{{ Request::url().'/'.$entry->getKey() }}/post" class="btn btn-xs btn-default">See Posts</a>

// outputs the URL
// http://awesome.app/admin/user/search/99/post
```

Notice the "search" term in the URL. That should be there. So how to properly remove it?

Comment: So I ended up using route() instead like so: `href="{{ route('my_route_name', $entry->getKey()) }}"`.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem

```
{{ str_replace('search/','',Request::url().'/'.$entry->getKey()) }}
```

fixed it for me

Comment: Works for me too, but I guess it should be more controllable on the API side rather than doing this workaround. Thanks anyways!